# How to create raster stack in ArcGis

Tags: arcgis, raster

In Idrisi software, its called rastergroup. In R, its called rasterstack. Is something like that exist in ArcGis?

The general idea is to 'group' all the raster layer in ArcGis, then convert it as a group into ASCII files.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and the scope of SO. It should have been posted on [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a grid (or raster) stack was alive and well in the GRID extension to ArcInfo Workstation but from what I can see in the ArcGIS documentation it no longer exists.

Rather than trying to make a stack to convert to a group of ASCII files why don't you use the batch grid of ArcGIS geoprocessing to do them that way?

Just locate the **[Raster To ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000005000000)** tool using the Search window and right-click on it to open it in batch mode - then you can just multiple-select your rasters from the Catalog window an drag and drop them into the batch grid.

Also, are you aware of the **[GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)** which was purpose built to resond to questions such as this?

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo for yor reply. Yup, I did finally used modelbuilder.
For the benefit of others, please see my post here
http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61394/17655